# how to create dynamic grid using javascript

Tags: javascript

---

### s.no.  | description

1. abcd1
2. abcd2
3. abcd3

i want to add more rows through input. now what i want is when i will add another row. let say {describtion="abcd4"}

### then the above grid will become

### s.no.  | description

1. abcd4
2. abcd1
3. abcd2
4. abcd3

meaning s.no. field got updated and new row will be added at top. adding a new row on top is no issue but how could i update s.no. at same time, here i want to ask is there any specific way to do this.

Comment: is using an ordered list an option?

Comment: From the description of the `grid` tag: "This tag is ambiguous, please don't use it." Your question is also ambiguous. HTML doesn't have "grids", only tables. There are probably various packages that implement spreadsheet-like grids, but in order to help you, we must know how you create the grid in the first place.

Comment: I would suggest to remove the algorithm tag, one can hardly think of this as an algorithm. Once it is clear what this *grid* represents, the population is straightforward.

Comment: Shouldn't last line read `4. abcd3` instead of `4. abcd4`?

Comment: @M Oehm @trincot , i choose description as single field here but in actual  
there are multiple fields like(testname,testtype, testcity etc. 20 field) but when i will add a row in the grid only s.no. will gonna change means 
it will get a new serial with 1 as newest added row in grid and so on and rest of the grid will not load. reloading a entire grid is not recommended for me because grid may have more than 10000 records

Comment: @trincot yes last line is 4. abcd3 .. my bad

Comment: What is grid? Do you mean `<table>`?

Comment: is this grid json array? or some other grid plugin you are referring to?

Comment: yeah maybe <table> or <div>, i can choose but have to insert through javascript

Comment: That still doesn't make a lot of sense to me. What exactly is a grid? Soemthing you display on a web page?

Comment: @Sachin , right now i am just having string from server but i will have it as json array, if it is a json array then how will i do it?no other grid plugin

Comment: @MOehm yes it is something look like grid on display.. just on display only.. what data transfer objects i should use? i am using spring and ajax (ofcourse page is loaded only once in entire page operation.. edit,delete etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that adds rows at the top of a table and keeps the numbers updated:

```js
document.querySelector('#btnadd').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var inp = document.querySelector('#inpadd');
  var descr = inp.value;
  if (descr === '') return; // do not add empty values
  var grid = document.querySelector('#grid');
  // first increment all row numbers
  for (var i = 1, row; row = grid.rows[i]; i++) {
    row.cells[0].textContent = i+1;
  }
  // add new row
  var row = grid.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.textContent = 1;
  cell2.textContent = descr;
  // clear input
  inp.value = "";
});
```

```html
New description: <input type="text" id="inpadd"><button id="btnadd">Add</button>
<table id="grid">
  <tr><th>s.no.</th><th>description</th></tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert new text description in the beginning of the ordered list, you can use 'insertBefore' javascript code:

```
list.insertBefore(entry, list.firstChild);
```

It should add the new text in the beginning of the list. Refer below code if it helps your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Input the text description and click 'Add Description' button to insert in list:</p>

<form>
Description Text:<br>
<input type="text" name="description" id="description">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Add Description" onclick='appendDescription()'>
</form>

<ol id="desclist">
<li>abcd1</li>
<li>abcd2</li>
<li>abcd3</li>
</ol>

<script>
function appendDescription(){
var description= document.getElementById('description').value;
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(description));

var list = document.getElementById('desclist');

list.insertBefore(entry, list.firstChild);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if some of the grid cell contain buttons and hyperlinks then how ordered list will work.. thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
function pushAtStarting(array, element){
    array.unshift(element); // new element has s.no = 0
    for (index in array){
       array[index].sno++
    }
}
var array = [];
pushAtStarting(array, {sno: 0, description: "abc"});
```

it works if your grid is java script arrays and elements are json elements.